# Spring Boot Cloud applications with Hystrix and Turbine not working with contextPath

Tags: spring-cloud, consul, hystrix, spring-cloud-netflix, turbine

I have a Spring Cloud Consul service that has two applications registered as `appservice1` and `appservice2`. Both applications are exposing a hystrix stream through: `http://ip1:8080/appservice1/hystrix.stream` and `http://ip2:8080/appservice2/hystrix.stream` so I can check metrics in another application with the Hystrix Dashboard.

I have created an application with Turbine to aggregate my both applications streams with the same cluster (CLUSTER_NAME) into the hystrix dashboard.

**Note: I dont even need to have a cluster for now, I just want both applications in the Hystrix Dashboard**

This is my `application.yml`:

```
turbine:
  aggregator:
    clusterConfig: CLUSTER_NAME
  appConfig: appservice1,appservice2
  instanceUrlSuffix.CLUSTER_NAME: /hystrix.stream
```

The problem here is since my both applications have a specific `server.contextPath`, turbine is not being able to locate the applications `/hystrix.stream` because is not building the url with each application context path.

The only way I got this working was with this `application.yml`:

```
turbine:
  aggregator:
    clusterConfig: appservice1,appservice2
  appConfig: appservice1,appservice2
  instanceUrlSuffix.appservice1: /appservice1/hystrix.stream
  instanceUrlSuffix.appservice2: /appservice2/hystrix.stream
```

But, this way I would have two clusters, one for each application, and that means I would have to insert each `/turbine.stream?cluster=appserviceX` separately into the dashboard.

Comment: First solution, could be to switch from pull to push model with ampq (your services would push messages to a queue, and turbine would read from it) and forget about using context paths. When you want to stick to pull model, I would recommend using actuator management ports to publish hystrix.stream (without any context path).

Comment: From what I can see, your configuration is correct and you need to specify one cluster at a time.

Comment: Thanks for your input @bart.s, that's actually a solution that I am going to consider in a later stage.

Comment: @spencergibb thanks for your input. If you have a look at the netflix's implementation of the interface `com.netflix.turbine.monitor.instance.InstanceUrlClosure` you can see that when the url is built, `processAttributeReplacements` is replacing the url placeholders with the Instance attributes. If in consul the service has a `contextPath` tag defined and I set `instanceUrlSuffix.appservice1: {contextPath}/hystrix.stream` it will work. It would be handy if it was covered in Spring's implementation available at `org.springframework.cloud.netflix.turbine.SpringClusterMonitor`. What do you think?